# Getview is not being called in custom adapter I debugged and I found position was being returned as -1

Tags: android

Below is the code for mycustom adapter.Getview is not being called in custom adapter I debugged and I found position was being returned as -1 in method

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return result.get(position);
    }

ArrayList   <searchObjects> result ;
        String [] title;
        Context context;
        int [] imageId;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        public CustomAdapter(searchresults mainActivity, 
    ArrayList<searchObjects> prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {       
            result=prgmNameList;
            context=mainActivity;
            imageId=prgmImages;

            inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I am calling custom adapterlike this

```
 lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        cst= new CustomAdapter(this, objects, prgmImages);
        lv.setAdapter(cst);
```

My full custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   ArrayList   <searchObjects> result ;
    String [] title;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(searchresults mainActivity, ArrayList<searchObjects> prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;

        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Custom get Item1", String.valueOf(result.size()));
        return result.size();
        //return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Custom get Item", String.valueOf(result.size()));
        return result.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView tv1;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.d("My custome adapter 1", "in view");
        Holder holder=new Holder();
        View rowView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlist, null);
        holder.tv1=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtvwsrchlistitemname);
        holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[0]);


        holder.tv1.setText(result.get(position).tmpSearchtitle);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

Main activity code

```
AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        cst= new CustomAdapter(this, objects, prgmImages);
        lv.setAdapter(cst);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object listItem = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Log.d(" Search results", " search results link cliked");
                Intent browser = new Intent(searchresults.this, locationdetails.class);
                startActivity(browser);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Need your full custom adapter

Comment: What value u are getting here  result.size();?

Comment: I am getting correct value in result.size as 2 but after that when I debug to see position field value it shows as -1 due to which it does not call my  public Object getItem(int position)  and eventually my getview

Comment: holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[0]);//can you comment this line and check whether are you getting the result ?

Comment: I tried now still not working

Comment: Would you post your xml file ?

Comment: Are u modifying the list in AsyncCallWS?

Comment: I am receiving my list in the form of Json object from webservice

Comment: Try the accepted answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391797/listview-not-getting-populated-getview-isnt-getting-called

Comment: Debug code which is executed which returns -1  mRecycler.setViewTypeCount(mAdapter.getViewTypeCount());

            int position;
            if (mStackFromBottom) {
                position = lookForSelectablePosition(mItemCount - 1, false);
            } else {
                position = lookForSelectablePosition(0, true);
            }
            setSelectedPositionInt(position);
            setNextSelectedPositionInt(position);

Comment: @SabaShamsher I actually wonder how you traced to this code .. 
As In fact I traced the code to find 0 as hardCoded parameter in the call hierarchy of getView()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing code I can suggest to you ,
if you'r using `AsyncTask` then you should update your `UI` in `onPostExecute()` method. So set your custom adapter in that method.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    cst= new CustomAdapter(this, objects, prgmImages);
    lv.setAdapter(cst);
 }
```

Also in custom adapter use `ViewHolder` pattern in `getView()` method which will prevent the duplication items while scrolling listView.

Comment: You'r wel come. You can accept my answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout. searchlist, null);
            holder = new Holder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id. txtvwsrchlistitemname);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        searchObjects rowItem = (searchObjects) getItem(position);

        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());

        return convertView;
    }
```

/** Your Pogo Class **/

```
public class searchObjects {
    private int imageId;

    private String desc;

    public searchObjects(int imageId,String desc) {
        this.imageId = imageId;

        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

}
```

Comment: change the name according to your requirement

Comment: can you update your code ,with the pogo class,and print this in your getview method,Log.e("text",""+rowItem.getDesc()) and Log.e("image",""+rowItem.getImageId())